# What is the correct bash script to retrieve all Azure Key Vault secrets

Tags: bash, azure

I have searched stackoverflow for a bash script for retrieving all the secrets of a Key Vault in Azure and storing the secrets in a csv file

The following is what I found and supposedly it worked for the OP.

```
az keyvault secret list --vault-name keyvault_A --query [].name -o tsv > /mnt/d/ubuntu/temp.csv
```

I tried the script above and below is my script.

```
az keyvault secret list --vault-name myVault --query [].name -o tsv > C:/user/main_user/documents/myFile.csv
```

The issue is it did not throw an error but it doesn't work either. I don't know what [].name and tsv are. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" is pretty vague; does *anything* happen? What was your expectation? What *specifically* happens instead? Is your `az` client authenticated?

Comment: `tsv` stands for Tab-Separated Values, it means the output file will have TAB characters between the columns.

Comment: `--query [].name` looks like a `jq` expression that extracts the `name` fields from an array of objects.

Comment: Yes, the az has been authenticated. I ran this command in Git Bash and my expectation is that my az key vault secrets should be written to my csv file but nothing happened. I go to check my csv file and I can see that the file size is still 0.

Comment: What if you just do `az keyvault secret list --vault-name myVault` without the rest?

Comment: I'm able to get data using ```az keyvault secret list --vault-name myVault```. I'm also able to get the secret name with the following ```az keyvault secret list --vault-name myVault --query [].name -o tsv```. It looks like I'm just not able to write to my csv file and I'm not sure why since it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Do you have the correct path for the file? If you paste the path without the filename (C:/user/main_user/documents/)  in Windows Explorer path bar or in Start - Run does it open the folder?
On windows it should be `c:\users` not `c:\user`

Comment: It does open the folder. I suspect I have a permission issue